# Cancel navigation for FMX TWebBrowser

Tags: delphi, twebbrowser, delphi-10.3-rio

I'm using using a TWebBrowser in a FireMonkey app (Delphi 10.3.3) and loading some dynamic HTML into it like this

```
DocumentWebBrowser.LoadFromStrings(browser_html,'');
```

In that HTML I have several links like

```
<a id="position_26" class="cdimmed" href="pos_26">SOME WORD</a>
```

I need to intercept when the user follows that link, without loading new HTML (just by running some JavaScript). `DocumentWebBrowserShouldStartLoadWithRequest` is never triggered. `DocumentWebBrowserDidStartLoad` is triggered, but I didn't find a way to stop the browser to stop the navigation. I tried calling `Stop`, `FinishLoading` and `FailLoadingWithError` without success. Any way to achieve this (without using CEF4)?

Comment: "*`DocumentWebBrowserShouldStartLoadWithRequest` is never triggered*" - it should be. If not, then [file a bug report](https://quality.embarcadero.com), if one doesn't already exist. "*I didn't find a way to stop the browser to stop the navigation*" - `TWebBrowser.Stop()` is the correct solution. If it does not work, file a bug report.

Comment: I will @RemyLebeau. Did some further testing and DocumentWebBrowserShouldStartLoadWithRequest is properly triggered in macOS, but never in Win 10. Implemented a workaround for Win10, using href="#pos_26". That way navigation doesn't occur and I can monitor the DidFinishLoad event.

Comment: This is the same issue in Delphi 11.0.  WebBrowser1ShouldStartLoadWithRequest(ASender: TObject;
  const URL: string); does not intercept everything.  If the user clicks on a link, it won't show up every time here.  It gets bypassed. Edit: using this on a Android 12 Pixel device.